# What is the correct way and place to get parent view's width and height from within a custom view?

Tags: android, android-view, android-custom-view, android-lifecycle, android-viewgroup

My custom view extends the `AppCompatImageView` class and it needs to know its parent view's dimensions. The following code is used:

```
val w = (parent as ViewGroup).width
val h = (parent as ViewGroup).height
```

**The problem:**

I am not sure where to implement this code. Ideally, I'd like it to be called only once per layout change and follow standard practice.

**I tried so far:**

overwriting the following methods of the [View class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View)

- `onAttachedToWindow` ⬅ This won't work, because `w` and `h` are always 0.
- `onMeasure` ⬅ It's not ideal. It yields zero for the first time and it's called multiple times.
- `onLayout` ⬅ It's not ideal as it's called multiple times as well.

Comment: Please see the linked duplicate question. This is a well-known problem and there are many possible solutions.